# Best place to coerce/convert to the right type in Python

Tags: python, dynamic-typing

I'm still fairly new to Python and I'm trying to get used to its dynamic typing. Sometimes I have a function or a class that expects a parameter of a certain type, but could get a value of another type that's coercible to it. For example, it might expect a `float` but instead receive an int or a decimal. Or it might expect a string, but instead receive an object that defines the `__str__` special method.

What is the best practice for coercing the argument to the right type (and the reason for it)? Do I do it in the function/class or in the caller? If in the caller, do I also check for it in the function? Eg.

**Alternative 1:**

```
def myfunc(takes_float):
    myval = float(takes_float)

myfunc(5)
```

**Alternative 2:**

```
def myfunc(takes_float):
    myval = takes_float

myfunc(float(5))
```

**Alternative 3:**

```
def myfunc(takes_float):
    assert isinstance(takes_float, float)
    myval = takes_float

myfunc(float(5))
```

I've already read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734368/type-checking-of-arguments-python-closed) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378927/what-is-the-best-idiomatic-way-to-check-the-type-of-a-python-variable) and they say that checking types in Python is "bad", but I don't want to waste time tracking down very simple bugs which would be instantly picked up by the compiler in a statically typed language.

Comment: Don't use `assert` like that.  Assertions are meant for documenting conditions that can't possibly happen at runtime, not for validating input.

Comment: Yes, can't possibly happen unless there's a bug. In alternative 3, where the caller must convert the value, it would be a bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You "coerce" (perhaps -- it could be a noop) when it's indispensable for you to do so, and no earlier.  For example, say you have a function that takes a float and returns the sum of its sine and cosine:

```
import math
def spc(x):
  math.sin(x) + math.cos(x)
```

Where should you "coerce" x to float?  Answer: nowhere at all -- sin and cos do that job for you, e.g.:

```
>>> spc(decimal.Decimal('1.9'))
0.62301052082391117
```

So when it is *indispensable* to coerce (as late as possible)?  For example, if you want to call string methods on an argument, you do have to make sure it's a string -- trying to call e.g. `.lower` on a non-string won't work, `len` might work but do something different than you expect if the arg is e.g. a list (give you the number of items in the list, not the number of characters its representation as a string will take up), and so forth.

As for catching errors -- think [unit tests](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4639) -- semidecent unit tests will catch all errors static typing would, and then some. But, that's a different subject.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends.  Why do you *need* a `float`?  Would an `int` break the function?  If so, why?

If you need the parameter to support a function/property that a `float` has but an `int` does not you should check for that function/property, *not* that the parameter happens to be a `float`.  Check that the object can do what you need it to do, not that it happens to be a particular type that you're familiar with.

Who knows, maybe someone will find some major problem with Python's implementation of `float` and create a `notbrokenfloat` library.  It might support everything a float does while fixing some exotic bug, but its objects wouldn't be of type `float`.  Manually casting it to a `float` might remove all the benefits of this nifty new class (or could break outright).

Yes, that's an unlikely example, but I think that's the right mindset to get into when working with a dynamically typed language.

Answer (score 0):

There is exactly one time when integer vs. float will be a problem.  This is the only time when you will find a "simple" bug that's weird and a challenge to debug.

Division.

Everything else does the conversion you need when you need it.

If you are using Python 2.x and casually throwing around `/` operators without thinking, you can -- under some common circumstances -- wind up doing the wrong thing.

You have several choices.

1. `from __future__ import division` will give you Python 3 semantics for division.
2. Run with the `-Qnew` option at all times to get the new division semantics.
3. Use `float` near `/` operations.

Division is the only place where type can matter.  It's the only time that integers behave differently from floats in a way that silently affects your results.

All other type mismatch problems will fail spectacularly with a `TypeError` exception.  All others.  You won't waste time debugging.  You'll know immediately what's wrong.

---

To be more specific.

There's no debugging of "expect a string but didn't get a string".  This will crash immediately with a traceback.  No confusion.  No time lost thinking.  If a function expects a string, then the caller must provide the string -- that's the rule.

Alternative 2 above is used RARELY to correct the problem where you have a function that expects a string AND you got confused and forgot to provide a string.  This mistake happens RARELY and it leads to an immediate type exception.

Comment: Thanks, good to know the options for that - but the int/float thing was just an example. There are other instances of the problem.

Comment: @Evgeny: Really?  Can you provide any?  The only one that's confusing is int/float.  AFAIK, All others die with obvious exceptions.  Please provide an example of an operation that doesn't die with an exception.

Comment: Another example is in my original post: the method might expect a string, but instead receive an object that defines the `__str__` special method. Somewhere along the line I need to call `str()` on it, but where?