# Get a python function attribute without running the function

Tags: python

I have a GUI which allows the user to run any function from a specific *.py file. I'd like some of the functions to run in a different manner than each other. In order to do that, I was trying to attach attributes to the function (Simple things like which inputs it needs). However, I found the only way to get those attributes was to run the code first.

Is there a way to get these attributes without running the code, or perhaps a more pythonic way to approach this task in general?

Very rudimentary example of my code:

FileA.py

```
def Beta(x):     
    Beta.input_stype = "Float"
    y = x + 0.5

    return y

def Gamma(x):  
    Gamma.input_stype = "String"
    y = x + "_blah_blah_blah"

    return y

def Delta(x): 
    Delta.input_stype = "String"
    y = x.index('WhereIsIt')

    return y
```

FileB.py

```
import FileA
import inspect

z = inspect.getmembers(Fiddle2, inspect.isfunction)

#### User selects the code value here ####

x = user_selection

executable = z[x][1] # Pulls the executable code

if executable.input_stype == "Float" :
    y = executable(45)
elif executable.input_stype == "String" :
    y = executable('Testing_the_WhereIsIt_stuff')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type checking of arguments Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734368/type-checking-of-arguments-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't assign the attributes inside the function body:

```
def Beta(x):
    y = x + 0.5
    return y
Beta.input_stype = "Float"
```

While you're at it, you may want to use the actual `float` or `str` types instead of the strings `"Float"` and `"String"`. If you're on Python 3, you may also want to use function annotations:

```
def Beta(x: float):
    y = x + 0.5
    return y
```

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You may also be able to make the code look a little cleaner, and keep the information closer to the function definition where people are more likely to look when reading your code, by using a decorator.

```
def input_stype(typ):
    def deco(f):
        f.input_stype = typ
        return f
    return deco

@input_stype('Float')
def Beta(x):
    ...

@input_stype('String')
def Gamma(x):
    ...
```

Comment: oh, I just noticed your answer.... I was working on my code and hadn't refreshed the screen

Comment: This works well, as long as I move the def input_stype(type) function to another py file. I'm pulling all functions in the given file, and this adds another function to it. 

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 3):

You can set the attribute right after the function definition:

```
def Beta(x):     
    y = x + 0.5
    return y

Beta.input_stype = "Float"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea I wanted to suggest:

```
def validate_input_type(typ):
    from functools import wraps
    def decorator(f):
        f.input_type = typ
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(arg):
            try:
                assert isinstance(arg, typ)
            except AssertionError:
                raise TypeError('{} is not of type {}'.format(arg, typ))
            return f(arg)
        return wrapper   
    return decorator
```

To be used like this:

```
@validate_input_type(float)
def foo(x):
    pass

@validate_input_type(str)
def bar(x):
    pass
```

This creates validation of the type of the arg at runtime AND sets input_type on the function for introspection.

Tests:

```
foo(1) -> TypeError
bar(1) -> TypeError
foo(1.0) -> Ok
bar('aaa') -> Ok

foo.input_type -> float
bar.input_type -> str
```

Comment: Newer versions of python (>=3.4) have a similar feature built-in using [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch).  You would still need to have a wrapper like yours to do everything within a single decorator though.  And it comes with the additional limitation that you can only have a single argument, which seems like a weird limitation.  Frankly, I'm kind of surprised the feature made it into python at all.