# How can I avoid type checking a python object if its attributes aren't used?

Tags: python

I've come across answers here for [type checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python) in general, type checking for [numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441358/python-most-pythonic-way-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-number), and type checking for [strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378927/what-is-the-best-idiomatic-way-to-check-the-type-of-a-python-variable).  Most people seem to respond by saying that type checking should **never** be performed in python (< 2.6) due to duck typing.  My (limited) understanding of duck typing is that type is determined by use of an object's attributes.  What do I do if I'm not using any attributes?

I have a simple function that determines constants based on the argument, which should be a number.  I raise an exception defined by

```
class outOfBoundsError(ValueError):
    """
    Specified value is outside the domain.
    """
```

with a message telling them the number they gave me is too big.  I would like to keep this message specific.  But if the argument is a string (like `'charlie'`), it still considers the argument to be greater than my specified number (and raises my exception).  Should I just add a dummy line to the code like `argument + 2` so that a TypeError is raised?

Note: I don't know anything about ABCs but I don't think they're available to me since the latest python version we have access to is 2.5 : (.

Comment: Anyone who tells you that you should *never* do something is wrong.  If you were *never* supposed to do that, then there wouldn't be convenient helper methods like `isinstance`.  You *usually* don't want to do that, and novices often fall back on it based on habits from other languages, but you should seriously question anyone who says *never*.

Comment: "Rules exist to make you *think* before breaking them."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common duck-typish Python solution to this problem is to (try to) convert what you got to what you need. For example, if you need an integer:

```
def getconstants(arg):
    try:
        arg = int(arg)
    except:
        raise TypeError("expected integer, or something that can be converted to one, but got " + repr(arg))
```

The `int` type constructor knows how to deal with many built-in types. Additionally, types that are convertible to an `int` type can implement the `__int__()` special method, which would allow them to be used here.  If the user passed in a string, that would work fine too as long as it contained only digits.

Your idea of performing some operation that could only be performed on a numeric type (such as adding 2) is similar, and would work great in many cases, but would fail with strings that can be converted to the desired type, so I like the type conversion better.

You could probably get by without the `try/except` here, since `int()` will raise either `TypeError` or `ValueError` if it can't do the conversion, but I think `TypeError` is more appropriate since you are *mainly* interested in the object's type, so I chose to catch the exception and always raise `TypeError`.

Answer (score 2):

My honest answer to

> Most people seem to respond by saying
>   that type checking should never be
>   performed in python (< 2.6) due to
>   duck typing

is: nonsense.

Type-checking - were needed - is common practice.

Don't listen to all and everything and don't accept every statement unfiltered.

Answer (score 1):

You can check to make sure you're expecting a type you support initially. i.e.

```
def foo(arg):
    if not isinstance(arg, int):
        raise TypeError
    ...
```

Nothing wrong with that if you're only supporting integers.

Answer (score 0):

Introspection works for this...primitive types have class names too:

```
>>> i=2
>>> i.__class__.__name__
'int'
>>> s="two"
>>> s.__class__.__name__
'str'
>>>
```