# How to check if a variable is a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

How would you check if a variable is a dictionary in Python?

For example, I'd like it to loop through the values in the dictionary until it finds a dictionary. Then, loop through the one it finds:

```py
dict = {'abc': 'abc', 'def': {'ghi': 'ghi', 'jkl': 'jkl'}}

for k, v in dict.items():
    if ###check if v is a dictionary:
        for k, v in v.iteritems():
            print(k, ' ', v)
    else:
        print(k, ' ', v)
```

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378927/what-is-the-best-idiomatic-way-to-check-the-type-of-a-python-variable (which is marked as a duplicate of the one above).

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2225038/770830

Comment: No, it is not the same question. The answer to this question and to the other questions listed here all contain substantially the same information. But the answer to "How to check if a variable is a dictionary in python" is "Use type() or isinstance()" which then leads to a new question, which is what is the difference between type() and isinstance(). But the person asking the first question can't possibly know that until the first question is answered. Ergo, different questions, which matters when you are looking for your question on the site.

Comment: I agree with @mbakeranalecta I came here looking for the answer to the question "How to check is a variable is a dictionary in Python?" and I would have never thought to look my answer into "Differences between isinstance() and type() in python".

Comment: For checking if a variable is a dictionary in particular, you should probably use `isinstance(v, collections.abc.Mapping)`. In other words, this is not an exact duplicate of "Differences between isinstance() and type()."

Answer (score 478, accepted):

Use [`isinstance(ele, dict)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), which will return true for `dict` objects as well as subclasses of `dict`, such as [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
d = {'abc': 'abc', 'def': {'ghi': 'ghi', 'jkl': 'jkl'}}
for element in d.values():
    if isinstance(element, dict):
       for k, v in element.items():
           print(k, ' ', v)
```

You can do `if type(ele) is dict` if you want to check strictly for instances of `dict` and not subclasses of it, though this is generally [not recommended](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Comment: I down-voted this answer because the right answer to the general question is: `isinstance(ele, collections.Mapping)`. It works for `dict()`, `collections.OrderedDict()`, and `collections.UserDict()`. The example in the question is specific enough for Padriac's answer to work, but it's not good enough for the general case.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because if you are going to to invoke `ele.items()` why are you checking type? EAFP/duck-typing works here, just wrap `for k,v in ele.items()` in `try...except (AttributeError, TypeError)`. If exception is raised, you know `ele` has no `items` that yields an iterable...

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Your hypothetical edge case would require that your "100% not a dict" custom class 1. had an `items()` method 2. which just so happened to yield an iterable and 3. where each element of that iterable can be represented as a 2-tuple. At this point your custom object has already implemented half of a dict already. For the purposes of the code listed we only cared about conditional expansion of the nested element, and your custom object already implements that. (It's a bit ironic that you criticize @Alexander Ryzhov's comment for being too general but now raise a general case)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'd rather not teach people-who-are-not-overly-familiar-with-Python anti-patterns to begin with. There are very few use-cases in Python that _require_ explicit typechecking - most stem from inheriting a bad implementation to begin with ('god object's, overriding standard library/language constructs, etc.) The original question is itself an XY problem. Why does the OP need to check type? Because according to their code what they really want to do is to check whether an item in their collection _behaves_ like a collection (implements `items()` that yields a nested iterable).

Comment: @AlexanderRyzhov Why not post that approach as an answer? BTW as Josh Kelley [has commented above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231989/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-a-dictionary-in-python#comment74495204_25231989) suggesting `collections.abc.Mapping`, a note might be appropriate that they’re the same, but `collections.abc` is not available before Python 3.3. `collections.Mapping` alias is still available in Python 3.6, but not documented, so probably one should prefer `collections.abc.Maping`.

Comment: I agree with Alexander Ryzhov's comment above and also downvoted the answer.

Comment: @AlexanderRyzhov `isinstance(collections.OrderedDict(), dict)` returns true, same with `defaultdict`. Not `UserDict` though.

Comment: Knowing that defaultdict also returns true was helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 105):

> ### How would you check if a variable is a dictionary in Python?

This is an excellent question, but it is unfortunate that the most upvoted answer leads with a poor recommendation, `type(obj) is dict`.

(Note that you should also not use `dict` as a variable name - it's the name of the builtin object.)

If you are writing code that will be imported and used by others, do not presume that they will use the dict builtin directly - making that presumption makes your code more inflexible and in this case, create easily hidden bugs that would not error the program out.

I strongly suggest, for the purposes of correctness, maintainability, and flexibility for future users, never having less flexible, unidiomatic expressions in your code when there are more flexible, idiomatic expressions.

`is` is a test for [object identity](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons). It does not support inheritance, it does not support any abstraction, and it does not support the interface.

So I will provide several options that do.

### Supporting inheritance:

This is the first recommendation I would make, because it allows for users to supply their own subclass of dict, or a `OrderedDict`, `defaultdict`, or `Counter` from the collections module:

`if isinstance(any_object, dict):`

But there are even more flexible options.

### Supporting abstractions:

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping

if isinstance(any_object, Mapping):
```

This allows the user of your code to use their own custom implementation of an abstract Mapping, which also includes any subclass of `dict`, and still get the correct behavior.

### Use the interface

You commonly hear the OOP advice, "program to an interface".

This strategy takes advantage of Python's polymorphism or duck-typing.

So just attempt to access the interface, catching the specific expected errors (`AttributeError` in case there is no `.items` and `TypeError` in case `items` is not callable) with a reasonable fallback - and now any class that implements that interface will give you its items (note `.iteritems()` is gone in Python 3):

```py
try:
    items = any_object.items()
except (AttributeError, TypeError):
    non_items_behavior(any_object)
else: # no exception raised
    for item in items: ...
```

Perhaps you might think using duck-typing like this goes too far in allowing for too many false positives, and it may be, depending on your objectives for this code.

### Conclusion

Don't use `is` to check types for standard control flow. Use `isinstance`, consider abstractions like `Mapping` or `MutableMapping`, and consider avoiding type-checking altogether, using the interface directly.

Comment: Well written explanation of the choices, and when/why to choose them.

Comment: I think it is too quick to jump into conclusion that "Don't use is to check types for standard control flow". We need to evaluate case-by-case basics. In some case, it is more desirable to have a strict check control, where you want to ensure it is the 1 and only 1 type, but not including its children.

Comment: At this point with mypy's static type checking and `match` coming out with cases that support inheritance, this answer needs to be updated somewhat with a bit more nuance all around.

Answer (score 7):

In python 3.6

```py
    typeVariable = type(variable)
    
    print('comparison',typeVariable == dict)

    if typeVariable == dict:
        #'true'
    else:
        #'false'
```

Answer (score 6):

The OP did not exclude the starting variable, so for completeness here is how to handle the generic case of processing a supposed dictionary that may include items as dictionaries.

Also following the pure Python(3.8) [recommended way](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.abc.html) to test for dictionary in the above comments.

```
from collections.abc import Mapping

my_dict = {'abc': 'abc', 'def': {'ghi': 'ghi', 'jkl': 'jkl'}}

def parse_dict(in_dict): 
    if isinstance(in_dict, Mapping):
        for k_outer, v_outer in in_dict.items():
            if isinstance(v_outer, Mapping):
                for k_inner, v_inner in v_outer.items():
                    print(k_inner, v_inner)
            else:
                print(k_outer, v_outer)

parse_dict(my_dict)
```

Comment: `dict.iteritems()` does not exist in Python 3, you should use `dict.items()` instead.

Comment: @Arkelis Oops, just copied/pasted that part, thanks for pointing it out - corrected now.

Comment: A comment on cosmetics -- To my eyes, the re-use of `k,v` in nested loops looks funky.  It also means that the inner `print(k,v)` does't represent the outer `k` in the displayed list.

Comment: @JesseChisholm, completely right, needs adjusting (done)!

Comment: How is it different from `typing.Mapping`?

Comment: @tejasvi88 It looks like an optimised vs generic approach. The collections builds on Abstract Base Classes for 'known' collections including dict above. The generic alternative (looks like a newer proposition) presumably makes this more generic to user-defined classes/collections. Hth

Comment: [`typing.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Mapping) is deprecated since Python 3.9 it seems, see docs.

Answer (score 4):

My testing has found this to work now we have type hints:

```
from typing import Dict

if isinstance(my_dict, Dict):
    # True
else:
    # False
```

Side note some discussion about typing.Dict [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087457/difference-between-defining-typing-dict-and-dict)