# Difference between defining typing.Dict and dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, type-hinting, python-typing

I am practicing using type hints in Python 3.5. One of my colleague uses `typing.Dict`:

```
import typing


def change_bandwidths(new_bandwidths: typing.Dict,
                      user_id: int,
                      user_name: str) -> bool:
    print(new_bandwidths, user_id, user_name)
    return False


def my_change_bandwidths(new_bandwidths: dict,
                         user_id: int,
                         user_name: str) ->bool:
    print(new_bandwidths, user_id, user_name)
    return True


def main():
    my_id, my_name = 23, "Tiras"
    simple_dict = {"Hello": "Moon"}
    change_bandwidths(simple_dict, my_id, my_name)
    new_dict = {"new": "energy source"}
    my_change_bandwidths(new_dict, my_id, my_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Both of them work just fine, there doesn't appear to be a difference.

I have read the [`typing` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Between `typing.Dict` or `dict` which one should I use in the program?

Comment: Note that Python doesn't actually *enforce* type hints. They are *just hints*, they are not used at runtime, or even compile time, to enforce types. Python may be strongly typed (opposite of weak typing), it is also *dynamically typed* (opposite of strict typing). See [Is Python strongly typed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11328920). External tools like mypy can use these hints to help you write better code, however, in a process called static analysis.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I used to love using type hints in my code alongside MyPy and pretending I could use Python with type safety. Unfortunately it got me A) code that doesn't work on < 3.4 and B) people laughing at me because apparently, type hints are a laughingstock. It's really quite unfortunate.

Comment: @cat: Type hinting was introduced to Python by a Facebook employee, because we had *enormous* success with adding the same feature to PHP (see [hack](http://hacklang.org/)). Anyone laughing has never built a big project with more than a handful of engineers.

Comment: @cat: MyPy supports python 3.2 and up, as well as 2.7, by the way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, `def a(b: int) -> bool:` is a syntax error in Python 2.7, and I think it's a syntax error in older versions of Python 3 too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I daresay anything except PHP would be better than PHP, but Hack seems to just try to make PHP even more Java++-y than the PHP devs already are. Not really on-topic, though :)

Comment: @cat: you are talking about *function annotations* here, syntax that was added to Python 3.0. So the only version where that is a syntax error is 2.7, which is why mypy supports putting that information in comments.

Comment: @cat: and indeed, we are now well into chatroom territory. Find me in the Python room if you are interested. Hack does not make PHP Java++-y; there is no static typing here. It makes PHP more like *Python*, if anything. Too verbose, still though.

Answer (score 345, accepted):

There is no real difference between using a plain `typing.Dict` and `dict`, no.

However, `typing.Dict` is a [*Generic type*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) <sup>*</sup> that lets you specify the type of the keys and values *too*, making it more flexible:

```
def change_bandwidths(new_bandwidths: typing.Dict[str, str],
                      user_id: int,
                      user_name: str) -> bool:
```

As such, it could well be that at some point in your project lifetime you want to define the dictionary argument a little more precisely, at which point expanding `typing.Dict` to `typing.Dict[key_type, value_type]` is a 'smaller' change than replacing `dict`.

You can make this even more generic by using [`Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Mapping) or [`MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.MutableMapping) types here; since your function doesn't need to *alter* the mapping, I'd stick with `Mapping`. A `dict` is one mapping, but you could create other objects that also satisfy the mapping interface, and your function might well still work with those:

```
def change_bandwidths(new_bandwidths: typing.Mapping[str, str],
                      user_id: int,
                      user_name: str) -> bool:
```

Now you are clearly telling other users of this function that your code won't actually *alter* the `new_bandwidths` mapping passed in.

Your actual implementation is merely expecting an object that is printable. That may be a test implementation, but as it stands your code would continue to work if you used `new_bandwidths: typing.Any`, because any object in Python is printable.

---

<sup>*</sup>: Note: If you are using Python 3.7 or newer, you can use `dict` as a generic type if you start your module with [`from __future__ import annotations`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/), and as of Python 3.9, `dict` (as well as other standard containers) [supports being used as generic type even without that directive](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/).

Comment: Useful additional examples would be when the dictionary values can be different types e.g. `{"name": "bob", "age" : 51}`, would that be something like`typing.Mapping[Union[str, int]` ? What about a nested dictionary like `{"person": {"name":"bob", "age": 51}` would that be something like `typing.Mapping[str, typing.Mapping[Union[str, int]]` ? Using `Union` like that troubles me because it's not a strict schema as there is no ordering. Maybe that's OK, or is there an alternative?

Comment: Nevermind about the `Union` question I see it's still an open discussion https://github.com/python/typing/issues/28

Comment: This seems to be very interesting, useful and related https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/

Comment: @GregHilston: that's actually about how to restrict what keys a dictionary can contain, and specify what types each associated value should have.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "specify what types each associated value should have." isn't that exactly what Davos is talking about above?

Comment: @GregHilston: ah, yes, it is.

Comment: I've also been told that `Mapping[A, B]` can accept a `Mapping[A, B1]` where `issubclass(B1, B)`, while a `Dict[A, B]` can't!

Comment: @xjcl: that's right, see the definitions for [`typing.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Mapping) (`VT_co` = *value type, covariant*) and [`typing.Dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Dict) (`VT` = *invariant*). It's about what the function _might_ do. `Mapping` is immutable, so a function that takes a mapping with both `B` and `B1` values will work if it sticks to treating everything as `B`. But `Dict` allows *mutation*; a function that takes a dict with `B` values only inserts `B` values, so passing in `Dict[A, B1]` would break other code!

Comment: @xjcl: see See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance for more.

Comment: @xjcl: that doesn't mean you can't pass in `{key: Bsubclass()}` to such a function, just that the dictionary there is annotated as `Dict[A, B]` and all other code treats the values only as `B()` instances, and not, without explicit checks, use any `Bsubclass`-specific attributes.

Comment: Per the samples in the typing documentation `dict[str, str]` is also valid, see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases

Comment: Isn't it so that Dict is being deprecated in favor of dict BUT dict will give an error in 3.8. You need at least 3.9. At least my program wont run on 3.8 if I have a dict or list typing hint.

Comment: @BrianReinhold: You can use `from __future__ import annotations` in Python 3.8, at which point the interpreter will stop trying to execute the annotations. Type checkers can still access the annotations and they all recognise `dict[str, str]`  annotations just fine. Or you can use a forward reference, by enclosing the annotation in quotes, so `"dict[str, str]"`.

Answer (score 40):

[`typing.Dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) is a generic version of `dict`:

> `class typing.Dict(dict, MutableMapping[KT, VT])`
>
> A generic version of dict. The usage of this type is as follows:
>
> ```
> def get_position_in_index(word_list: Dict[str, int], word: str) -> int:
>      return word_list[word]
> ```

Here you can specify the type of key and values in the dict: `Dict[str, int]`

Answer (score 16):

as said in [python org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Dict):

> class typing.Dict(dict, MutableMapping[KT, VT])

> A generic version of dict. Useful for annotating return types. To
> annotate arguments it is preferred to use an abstract collection type
> such as Mapping.

This type can be used as follows:

```
def count_words(text: str) -> Dict[str, int]:
    ...
```

But `dict` is less general and you will be able to alter the mapping passed in.
In fact, in `python.Dict` you specify more details.

Another tip:

> Deprecated since version 3.9: builtins.dict now supports []. See [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/#id6)
> and Generic Alias Type.

Comment: Very good to point out the deprecation of `typing.Dict`.

Comment: does this mean typing.Dict[str, str] is the same as dict[str, str] now?

Answer (score 7):

If you're coming from google for
`TypeError: Too few parameters for typing.Dict; actual 1, expected 2`, you need to provide a type for both the key and value.

So, `Dict[str, str]` instead of `Dict[str]`