# Using List/Tuple/etc. from typing vs directly referring type as list/tuple/etc

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

What's the difference of using `List`, `Tuple`, etc. from `typing` module:

```
from typing import Tuple

def f(points: Tuple):
    return map(do_stuff, points)
```

As opposed to referring to Python's types directly:

```
def f(points: tuple):
    return map(do_stuff, points)
```

And when should I use one over the other?

Comment: Give this a read, I found myself asking the same question you had until I read this. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: [Tuple, used by listing the element types. for example Tuple\[int, int, str\]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-typing-module)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087457/difference-between-defining-typing-dict-and-dict

Answer (score 311, accepted):

Until Python 3.9 [added support for type hinting using standard collections](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections), you had to use `typing.Tuple` and `typing.List` if you wanted to document what type the *contents* of the containers needed to be:

```
def f(points: Tuple[float, float]):
    return map(do_stuff, points)
```

Up until Python 3.8, `tuple` and `list` did not support being [used as *generic types*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics). The above example documents that the function `f` requires the `points` argument to be a tuple with two `float` values.

[`typing.Tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple) is special here in that it lets you specify a specific number of elements expected and the type of each position. Use ellipsis if the length is not set and the type should be repeated: `Tuple[float, ...]` describes a variable-length `tuple` with `float`s.

For [`typing.List`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) and other sequence types you generally only specify the type for all elements; `List[str]` is a list of strings, of any size. Note that functions should preferentially take [`typing.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence) as arguments and `typing.List` is typically only used for return types; generally speaking most functions would take any sequence and only iterate, but when you return a `list`, you really are returning a specific, mutable sequence type.

If you still need to support Python 3.8 or older code, you should always pick the `typing` generics even when you are not currently restricting the contents. It is easier to add that constraint later with a generic type as the resulting change will be smaller.

If you are implementing a custom container type and want that type to support generics, you can [implement a `__class_getitem__` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-generic-types) or inherit from [`typing.Generic`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic) (which in turn implements `__class_getitem__`).

Comment: What about the advantage of List[] over []. If personally find the first nicer but I have no argmuent in a code review for example :)

Comment: @Samos Both would be utilizing [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) but [] isn't described in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), or [the extension PEPs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). By not following the standard you don't get the benefits of tools that _only_ follow the standard. E.g. mypy may not work.

Comment: "Note that functions should preferentially take typing.Sequence as arguments and typing.List is typically only used for return types; generally speaking most functions would take any sequence and only iterate, but when you return a list, you really are returning a specific, mutable sequence type." Why shouldn't functions return a sequence?

Comment: @kolistivra: because that limits what a caller can do with the returned list object. Anything that requires, say, a *mutable* sequence won't accept the return value. Or if something specifically requires a list for whatever reason, you can use the return value either. Set your return value as specific as you can make it.

Comment: Don't forget to `from typing import Tuple`

Comment: Per the samples in the typing documentation `list[float]` is also valid, see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases

Comment: @haridsv: that's [new in Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections), which came out in October 2020, so 4 years after I wrote this answer. I've updated it to reflect the changed landscape.

Comment: Your last paragraph seems incorrect. "To implement custom generic classes that can be parameterized at runtime and understood by static type-checkers, users should either inherit from a standard library class that already implements `__class_getitem__()`, or inherit from `typing.Generic`, which has its own implementation of `__class_getitem__()`." `__class_getitem__` is mostly an implementation detail to work around the limitations of metaclasses.

Comment: @Peilonrayz: I don't see how that makes my last sentence incorrect. I can add a mention of `typing.Generic`, but to dismiss `__class_getitem__` as an implementation detail is not a fair characterisation.

Answer (score 163):

From Python 3.9 ([PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/)) onwards `tuple`, `list` and various other classes are now generic types. Using these rather than their `typing` counterpart is now preferred. From Python 3.9 you can now just do:

```py
def f(points: tuple[float, float]):
    return map(do_stuff, points)
```

If you don't need to evaluate your type hints then you can use this syntax in Python 3.7+ due to [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/).

```py
from __future__ import annotations


def f(points: tuple[float, float]):
    return map(do_stuff, points)
```

---

You should always pick then non-`typing` generic whenever possible as the old `typing.Tuple`, `typing.List` and [other generics](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/#implementation) are deprecated and will be removed in a later version of  Python.

> Importing those from `typing` is deprecated. Due to [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) and the intention to minimize the runtime impact of typing, this deprecation will not generate DeprecationWarnings. Instead, type checkers may warn about such deprecated usage when the target version of the checked program is signalled to be Python 3.9 or newer. It's recommended to allow for those warnings to be silenced on a project-wide basis.
>
> The deprecated functionality will be removed from the typing module in the first Python version released 5 years after the release of Python 3.9.0.

Comment: *"Using these rather than their typing counterpart is now preferred."* For public python libraries, doesn't it make sense to continue using the `typing` generics for 4 years after the release of Python 3.9.0?

Comment: Not disagreeing @MateenUlhaq, but can you share why it makes sense?

Comment: @MonkeySeeMonkeyDo So the libraries work on Python 3.0+. Whilst you can just manually perform what `__future__.annotations` does (`def f(points: "tuple[float, float]")`) the code won't work if you need to evaluate the type hints at run time.

Comment: Note that you must use square brackets - `[` and `]` - for typing. If you try `tuple(float, float)` you'll get `TypeError: tuple expected at most 1 argument, got 2`

Comment: It depends whether you're focussed on legacy support or future longevity. The sooner you move onto the new canonical forms the sooner your code is proofed for future upgrades where the old forms are depreciated. Surely you decide on a Python version you're going to use and use that version? Why would you deploy Python 3.10 and still code in Python 3.8?

Answer (score 6):

tl;dr:

As of Python 3.9, type aliases like `List`, `Tuple`, `Dict`, ... are [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#deprecated-aliases).

So, from then on, use the built-in types `list`, `tuple`, `dict`, ...