# Static typing in python3: list vs List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, static-typing

What is the difference between using list and List when defining for example the argument of a function in python3? For example, what is the difference between

```
def do_something(vars: list):
```

and

```
def do_something(vars: List):
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) says:

> class typing.List(list, MutableSequence[T])
>
> Generic version of list. Useful for annotating return types.

but I'm not entirely sure what the above means.

I have similar questions for: dict vs Dict, set vs Set, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using List/Tuple/etc. from typing vs directly referring type as list/tuple/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458193/using-list-tuple-etc-from-typing-vs-directly-referring-type-as-list-tuple-etc)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not all lists are the same from a typing perspective.  The program

```
def f(some_list: list):
    return [i+2 for i in some_list]

f(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

won't fail a static type checker, even though it won't run.  By contrast, you can specify the contents of the list using the abstract types from `typing`

```
def f(some_list: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    return [i+2 for i in some_list]

f(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

will fail, as it should.

Comment: Note: PEP 585 changes this in Python 3.9. Lowercase `list[int]` works now.

Comment: @ScottJ So is list and List now completely the same?

Comment: @SearchSpace I'm not sure, but it seems capital List is no longer needed?

Comment: using `list` instead of `List` as typing annotation in python 3.8 and older will cause `Typeerror: type object is not subscriptable `

Comment: @ScottJ @SearchSpace Just read the docs. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#special-forms
All the Types like `List`, `Dict`, etc (with a capital letter) were deprecated since Python 3.9
e.g. `Deprecated since version 3.9: builtins.tuple now supports []. See PEP 585 and Generic Alias Type.`
You can use just `list` instead. The old types are left for backwards compatibility if you need to use them.