# How to check which version of Python a codebase was written in?

Tags: python, git, version

There is a repo that I have access to and after cloning onto my local machine I am getting syntax errors from the script. Is there any way to accurately check which version it was originally written in?

Comment: Assuming you don't have a `Pipfile`, `setup.py`, or Heroku `runtime.txt` or similar that might specify supported versions, I'd start by looking at the specific syntax errors you're getting. That should help narrow things down pretty quickly.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not.  Perhaps the best you can do with an empirical test, is to bisect the search space: try a "middle" Python version, and then move older or newer as befits the result.

You can cut down this search somewhat by noting distinctive features in the the code.  For instance, using `print` as a command, rather than a function call, suggests Python 2.7 or earlier; f-strings did not appear until 3.6 (thanks to Chris for the correction).

Still, there is no built-in identification -- especially as the question isn't entirely deterministic.  For instance, `print(value)` will *work* in Python 2.6, although it suggests Python 3.

Also, it's quite possible to be "writing in" a particular Python version without using any of that versions upgrades.  Some of my professional code is aimed at 3.6 and later, although most of is runs in 3.4, and a few modules will function properly in 2.7.

Comment: You can also check if there are any uses of `match`-`case` statements as this was brought in in 3.11. Additionally, if there are any mentions of List, Tuple, etc. from `typing` module, then this suggests <3.9 (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458193/using-list-tuple-etc-from-typing-vs-directly-referring-type-as-list-tuple-etc)