# Python type hinting for function with keras model

Tags: python, keras, type-hinting

If I create function like this:

```
def mdl(input_shape):

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(depth=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(32), activation='relu')
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(32), activation='relu')
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(16), activation='relu')
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    return model
```

and I care a lot about good programming practices, how should I indicate returning type of the function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def mdl(input_shape) -> Sequential:
```

You probably also want to type the input_shape. I am guessing it is a tuple of ints, so:

```
def mdl(input_shape: Tuple[int, ...]) -> Sequential:
```

If you are interested in best practice, you may want to use a better, more semantic function name as well, e.g. `build_model`.

Comment: How can I import those types? If i try to do this my IDE only tells me ""Sequential" is not defined"

Comment: @Max — you can use `from keras import Sequential` ([docs](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/)) and `from typing import Tuple` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)); for Python 3.9+, you can just use the built-in `tuple` type instead of `Tuple`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39458225/3618671) for details.