# Why use Type Hinting over the actual type of the variable itself in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Let's say I want to declare a function in two manners below:

```
from Typing import List

def func(nums: List[int]):
```

vs.

```
def func(nums: list[int]):
```

Is there any difference in terms of performance or is it just for readability?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using List/Tuple/etc. from typing vs directly referring type as list/tuple/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458193/using-list-tuple-etc-from-typing-vs-directly-referring-type-as-list-tuple-etc)

Comment: Since type hinting is purely ornamental, I'd guess the additional import might minimally impact your performance.  You do know you can put anything into that variable, regardless of the type hint, right?