# Python typing to return tuple of multiple arguments type variables

Tags: python, typing

I already have a function that returns a value according to the type it receives as its argument:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', int, str)

def get(t: Type[T]) -> T: ...
```

So that `get(int)` returns an `int` and `get(str)` returns a `str`.

I also have a version of `get` that is used to get many values as a tuple:

```py
def get_many(*ts: Type[T]):
    return tuple(get(t) for t in ts)
```

How should the return type of `get_many` be annotated?

To be clear, `get_many(int, str)` should return `tuple[int, str]`,  `get_many(str, str, int)` should return `tuple[str, str, int]` and so on.

Comment: tuple([type(ts) for item in ts]) ?

Comment: @PicxyB: I am afraid no calls are allowed in type declarations, they must be static.

Comment: I don't think this is possible; it requires support for type-level lists (which would be a list of types, not the type of list of types.)

Comment: So I'm guessing just `tuple[T]`, which seems most intuitive to me, doesn't work? You are, afterall, returning a tuple containing elements of type `T`, although as I write this I'm starting to think that might not actually be right...

Comment: @joanis: It does not work as tuple[T] is a tuple with just one element of type T.

Comment: Right. I still haven't got my head fully wrapped around Python's weird typing system. Maybe `Tuple[T, ...]`, from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39458225/3216427

Comment: @joanis: Thanks for the link, I did not know about this ellipsis. But it does not seem to help in this case: "Tuple[float, ...] describes a variable-length tuple with floats". Different types cannot be used.

Comment: But once you define typevar `T`, can't you use it here? If `T` is the union of the types that might occur in that tuple, I don't really understand why that doesn't work. Or else fall back to a plain `Union`: `Tuple[Union[str, int, whatever], ...]`. Did I mention I hate Python typing?