# Python 3.10 Type Hinting causes Syntax Error

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-3.10

I have defined two classes. A `Bookshelf` class and a `Book` class and have defined each with its own methods and type hints. When I run the below code in VS Code using python 3.10 it comes up with the following error:

```
class Bookshelf: 
SyntaxError: Invalid syntax
```

Which is referring to the init of the `BookShelf` class below. Can any of you spot the issue?

```py
class Bookshelf:

    def __init__(self, books: list[Book]):
        self.books = books

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Bookshelf with {len(self.books)}"


class Book:
    def __init__(self, name: str, page_count: int):
        self.name=name
        self.page_count = page_count
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a `SyntaxError`, It is a `NameError` because `Book` class is not defined yet when you are using it in your type hints.

**1. First solution** is moving the definition of `Book` class before the `BookShelf`.

**2. Second solution** is use the string instead of the `book` itself:

```py
def __init__(self, books: list["Book"]):
```

I think in Python 3.11, They will allow to use it as it is. Evaluation of type annotations are gonna be postponed:

https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/

**3. third solution**: If you want to have this now, you can import:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
```

then your code is going to work.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works a treat and as you say in the second option overcomes the control flow / name error issue, even though I could simply put my Book class before my BookShelf class

Answer (score 2):

Using the code in your question, I'm actually getting a `NameError` because `Book` is used in the type hint before it's defined. Moving the `Book` class above `Bookshelf` took care of it.

```py
class Book:
    def __init__(self, name: str, page_count: int):
        self.name = name
        self.page_count = page_count


class Bookshelf:
    def __init__(self, books: list[Book]):
        self.books = books

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Bookshelf with {len(self.books)} books."

atlas = Book("Atlas", 100)
dictionary = Book("Dictionary", 1000)
print(atlas)
print(Bookshelf([atlas, dictionary]))
```

Output:

```
<__main__.Book object at 0x7f61af441fd0>
Bookshelf with 2 books.
```

Comment: Thank you. I just noticed that I was using Book in my BookShelf class before it was defined in my Book class.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching:

```py
list[Book]
```

with:

```py
'list[Book]'
```

Comment: It still returns the same error on the same line. No difference

Comment: Try checking again, it worked for me with that change.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have defined the `Book` class after you referred to it in `books: list[Book]`
2. You can't use `list[Book]` as a parameter as the type `list` is already defined in Python

Try this:

```py
from typing import List #Using typing's List instead of list

class Book:
    def __init__(self, name: str, page_count: int):
        self.name=name
        self.page_count = page_count
#Defined book class before its use
        
list_of_books = List[Book] #Using a type alias to solve the problem so you can use it as a parameter

class Bookshelf:

    def __init__(self, books: list_of_books):
        self.books = books

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Bookshelf with {len(self.books)}"
```

Use [type aliases](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases) to define the complex type of parameter you want.
See [Using List/Tuple/etc. from typing vs directly referring type as list/tuple/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458193/using-list-tuple-etc-from-typing-vs-directly-referring-type-as-list-tuple-etc)

Comment: *You can't use list[Book] as a parameter as the type list is already defined in Python* No it's perfectly fine to use `list[]`. Since Python 3.9 (I think), built-in types became generic types.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary but the OP is using Python 3.10.

Comment: Isn't Python 3.10 newer than Python 3.9 ?

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary, oh sorry. I didn't think or notice why people say Python `3.10` and not `3.1`. I thought it's Python 3.1 so 3.9 is newer.