# Initialise dictionary variable with types of var/obj

Tags: python-3.x

I was wondering if it is possible to define the type of keys and values of a dictionary can take when you initialise a dict.

I was expecting something like that :

```
myDict = dict(int, aClass)
```

or

```
myDict = dict[int, aClass]
```

i know how to declare a dictbut what i want is to code "This dict can only take a int as key and an instance of MyClass as a value"

but it does not work.

Thank you very much!

FinnStark

Comment: I believe that your question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087457/difference-between-defining-typing-dict-and-dict)

Comment: Thanks Theodoros, typing.Dict[int, int] works but typing.Dict[int, MyClass] does not works : TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got <module 'utils.MyClass' from

Answer (score 0):

```
myDict = {
    "key1": "value1"
}
```

Comment: i know how to declare a dict, ty but what i want is to write "This dict can only take a int as key and an instance of MyClass as a value"

Comment: I don’t think that python supports this as a dynamically typed language the same way that something like java has things like Map<Integer, Object>. You could write your own class that wraps a dictionary and checks the object types at runtime but you won’t be able to have it fail at “compile time” (although that doesn’t really exist for python anyway).