# Type hinting produces "TypeError: type object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

`w: dict[int, int] = {1:2, 2:3, 69: 420}` produces the error message in the title.  Why won't specific type hints work for my dictionaries and lists?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes.  Why didn't DDG put that as the top result when I searched for the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of python3.8, you need to **import their respective classes from the `typing` module**.

```py
from typing import Dict, List, Set

w: Dict[int, int] = {1:2, 2:3, 69:420}
```

Note the capital D in `Dict`.

Comment: This is well known and very possibly covered in other questions. There's no need for a self-answered question.

Comment: For example, the topic is comprehensively covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087457/difference-between-defining-typing-dict-and-dict

Comment: The question you linked did not appear in the Google results for the error nor in the suggested duplicates box when typing the question.