# If conditional that checks on variable type (int, float, ect)

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

Python3: I wish to know if I can set up an if statement to execute some code just like one normally would.

But I want the statement to go something like this: (psudo-code)

```
If variable1 !== "variable type integer":
    then break.
```

Is this possible?  Thanks for the help.

I apologize if this has already been addressed, but the search suggester bot didn't have any posts to point me to.

Jesse, NOOb

Comment: Do you have a particular language in mind?

Comment: Sorry:  It is Python3  running on OSX yosemite

Comment: looks like javascript? You should add a Python3 tag to your post

Comment: thanks, getting the hang of this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best (idiomatic) way to check the type of a Python variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378927/what-is-the-best-idiomatic-way-to-check-the-type-of-a-python-variable)

Comment: This is not a common pattern in Python - why do you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Usually it's better to use `isinstance`, so you accept variables that quack like ducks, too:

```
>>> isinstance(3.14, int)
False
>>> isinstance(4, int)
True
>>> class foo(int):
...     def bar(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> f = foo()
>>> isinstance(f, int)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import the types and check variables against them:

```
>>> from types import *

>>> answer = 42

>>> pi = 3.14159

>>> type(answer) is int # IntType for Python2
True

>>> type(pi) is int
False

>>> type(pi) is float # FloatType for Python 2
True
```

For your more specific case, you would use something like:

```
if type(variable1) is int:
    print "It's an int"
else:
    print "It isn't"
```

---

Just keep in mind that this is for a variable that already exists as the correct type.

If, as you may be indicating in your comment (`if user_input !== "input that is numeric"`), your intent is to try and figure out whether what a user entered is valid for a given type, you should try a different way, something along the lines of:

```
xstr = "123.4"             # would use input() usually.
try:
    int(xstr)              # or float(xstr)
except ValueError:
    print ('not int')      # or 'not float'
```

Comment: isnt pi a float type?  And if I understand you correctly, this is pulling from a "types" module?  Basically I just need a way of executing a break statement by using an if. 

if user_input !== "input that is numeric"

Comment: @user3321476, yes, it's a float type, which is why `type(pi) is int` gave you false. I've added the Python3-specific ones, relegating Python2 to comments, and given a more concrete example for you at the bottom.

Comment: sweet, i get it now, you rock!

Comment: @user3321476, hopefully, I'll rock enough to get an upvote and/or accept. Nudge nudge, wink, wink :-)