# How do I make an if statement that can only take integers ? python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm really new to python and I'm trying to make an if else statement that can only take integers. I'm trying to make something like this:

```
num = (input("Enter a number:"))
if (num is an int):
   num = num*2
elif (num is a str):
   print("please enter a number")
```

Comment: num1 will always be a string, python3 input is similar to raw_input from python2. You can either try to convert it to an int and manage the exception, or you can check if the string is a valid integer string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best (idiomatic) way to check the type of a Python variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378927/what-is-the-best-idiomatic-way-to-check-the-type-of-a-python-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this.

```
isinstance(<var>, int)
```

unless you are in Python 2.x in which case you want:

```
isinstance(<var>, (int, long))
```

Also, keep in mind that your code will always recive a string because the input function recives the keyboard input as a string.

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

By default `input()` takes argument as `str`.

To convert it into `int` you can do

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number:"))
```

If it is not number above code will throw an error.

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'

To overcome this you can use `try-except` (Exception handling)

```
try:
    num1 = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    num1 = num1*2
except:
    print("please enter a number")
```