# Handling different return types for Exceptions

Tags: python

I am working on a small texting application using Twilio API. Recently, I had some issues with the API so I added an `Exception` in my `get_current_credits()` function.

I am quite new to Python and programming in general and I would like to know what would be the cleanest way to do that.

If the `Exception` is throw, I only return a `String`. If not, I am returning a `tuple`. What would be the cleanest way to see what was the return from my `inject_credits()` function, I am thinking about `type(res)` but does seems a quick and dirty solution?

```
def get_current_credits():
    try:
        balance_data = twilio_client.api.v2010.balance.fetch()
        balance = float(balance_data.balance)
        currency = balance_data.currency
        return balance, currency  
    except Exception:
        return "503 Service Unavailable"

def inject_credit():
    res = get_current_credits()
    # if Exception:
       # return the Exception message as a string
    # else, do the following: 
    (credit, currency) = res
    if currency != "EUR":
        credit = currency_converter.convert(credit, currency, 'EUR')
    return dict(credit=(round(credit,2)))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378927/what-is-the-best-idiomatic-way-to-check-the-type-of-a-python-variable

Answer (score 1):

You could move the Exception outside, into the body of `inject_credit`. Thus, you don't have to do any if statements inside `inject_credit`, you can just catch the Exception there itself.

Checking the type isn't a bad idea, but it is not very clear what is being done if someone is only reading `inject_credit`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if type(get_current_credits()) == str:
    # Do something if it is a string
else:
    # Do something if it is a tuple
```

However, the best way would be to add the `try` statement outside of the function so that you can catch the exception there instead.

```
try:
    get_current_credits()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    # Do whatever
```